# Wrapping around 360 degrees with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I am fairly new with using SQL and I would like to learn how to efficiently filter a data set of ecliptic coordinates (longitude, latitude) for regions of the sky. The data set is in the southern ecliptic hemisphere (from -90 to 0 and 0 to 360) as shown below (simulated in Python with some simple numpy arange commands).

[image]

I have figured out how to filter a specific patch of the sky in python with the following code:

```
x = (eclong + 360 - center) % 360
ind = x > 180
x[ind] = x[ind] - 360 #converts from 0 to 360 to -180 to +180
x = -x #reverses scale where east direction is on left
```

To allow data points to wrap around the South pole, I also have an additional required condition:

```
filtered_eclong = (x < 12/np.cos(eclat *np.pi/180)) & (-12/np.cos(eclat *np.pi/180) < x & eclat < 0)
```

12 degrees is how wide the patch of sky that I want to grab is and center is a variable for the central ecliptic longitude of my desired patch of sky. The last line in the query is a correction to include objects near the southern ecliptic pole. (Note: eclat = ecliptic latitude , eclong = ecliptic longitude, both in degrees) As an example of the results I would like to get, the patch of sky I want to filter is centered on a ecliptic longitude of 315.8 degrees, seen below:

[image]

I've saved the entire simulated southern hemisphere as a csv file and uploaded the eclong and eclat values as columns in a sql database. I would like to be able to recreate the same query I performed in my Python code above. This is the closest attempt I have:

```
select * from coords
    where eclat < -6
    and mod(abs(eclong-315.8+360),360)-360 < 180
    and mod(abs(eclong-315.8),360) < 12/cos(radians(eclat));
```

which produces this result where the filtered Python result is shown in red and the filtered sql result is shown in blue:

[image]

As shown, my query doesn't include things that wrap around from 360 degrees to 0 degrees and I'm not quite sure how to include those missing points.

I think using some combination of THEN, ELSE or CASE statements would help:

```
select * from Catalog
where eclat < -6
CASE
    WHEN mod(abs(eclong-315.8),360) < 12/cos(radians(eclat)) > 0 THEN 'I'm not sure what to do...'
    WHEN mod(abs(eclong-315.8),360) < 12/cos(radians(eclat)) < 360 THEN 'I'm not sure what to do...'
into myDB.filename
```

Any SQL gurus out there?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added some visuals to help with clarity and generalization.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not familiar with ecliptic coordinates, it sounds like you're trying to reconcile the lack of negative numbers based on your title. If that's indeed what you're going for, who cares that there aren't any negative values—let's pretend there are!

To generalize, we'll need to ensure we can safely calculate ±180 degrees from any starting longitude. With this use case, starting from 11 degrees, we could rearrange the unhelpful values by subtracting 360 from anything greater than `11 + 180` and working with the result as a helper. This way, 359 degrees would instead show up as -1, and then you can do normal math. If your starting longitude is above 180, we'd need to get the lowest values above 360. In SQL, here's a (maybe inefficient, but straightforward) way I'd create a helper column:

```
CASE
    WHEN center < 180 THEN CASE
                               WHEN eclong > center + 180 THEN eclong - 360
                               ELSE eclong
                           END
    WHEN center > 180 THEN CASE
                               WHEN eclong < center - 180 THEN eclong + 360
                               ELSE eclong
                           END
    ELSE eclong
END as friendly_eclong
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it helped me think of how to better visualize and test my original question. There are a couple of questions I have about your suggested approach. Would this "center" term be in reference to some region I define or does this act as a variable within this case when then else end commands? If it is some arbitrary number and not a variable, I experience syntax errors with these commands. 

I'm not well versed in sql (learning more everyday!) and I'm not sure how to debug these case statements. As far as I can tell, it seems right.